# Keras Error when checking : expected embedding_1_input to have shape (None, 100) but got array with shape (1, 3)

Tags: python, keras, imdbpy

I created LSTM model using imdb example and tried to predict sentiment in my own string

```
max_features = 20000
# cut texts after this number of words
# (among top max_features most common words)
maxlen = 100
batch_size = 32


wordsA = "I like this review"

wordIndexes = imdb.get_word_index()

wordArray = wordsA.split()
intArray = []
for word in wordArray:
    if word in wordIndexes:
        intArray.append(wordIndexes[word])

testArray = np.array([intArray])

print('Shape: '+str(testArray.shape)) 

model = load_model('my_model2.h5')

print(str(testArray))

prediction = model.predict(testArray)
print(prediction)
```

But when I try to do prediction I get errored with following traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Radosław/nauka/python/SentimentAnalysis/sentiment_console.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Radosław/nauka/python/SentimentAnalysis')
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 866, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:/Users/Radosław/nauka/python/SentimentAnalysis/sentiment_console.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       prediction = model.predict(testArray)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py",
>   line 899, in predict
>       return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1555, in predict
>       check_batch_axis=False)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 133, in _standardize_input_data
>       str(array.shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking : expected embedding_1_input to have
>   shape (None, 100) but got array with shape (1, 3)

is there is proper way to reshape my input array?

Comment: How is defined the model that  you are loading? It's probably defining an input shape of length 100 words. The way to treat variable message/text length is to pad the short ones and clip the long ones, so that your input is always 100 words long

Answer (score 1):

You did everything but forgot the sequence padding. Add this line before calling predict.

```
testArray = sequence.pad_sequences(testArray, maxlen=maxlen)
```